# Nodejs mongo return data with pagination information

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using node and mongo with the native client.

I would like to add pagination to my application.

To get pagination, I need my responses to always return `count` alongside `data`

I would like to get something like:

```
{
   count : 111, 
   data : [ { 'a' : 'only first item was requested' } ]
}
```

I can do this in mongo

```
> var guy  = db.users.find({}).limit(1)
> guy.count()
11
> guy.toArray()
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5381a7c004fb02b10b557ee3"),
        "email" : "myEmail@guy.com",
        "fullName" : "guy mograbi",
        "isAdmin" : true,
        "password" : "fe20a1f102f49ce45d1170503b4761ef277bb6f",
        "username" : "guy",
        "validated" : true
    }
]
```

but when I do the same with nodejs mongo client I get errors.

```
var cursor = collection.find().limit(1);
cursor.toArray( function(){ .. my callback .. });
cursor.count();
```

It seems that

- `count` is not defined on cursor
- that once I applied `toArray` on cursor, I cannot use the cursor again

How, using nodejs, can I accomplish the same thing I can with mongo directly?

Comment: which `client` you are using?

Comment: native nodejs mongo client. I am stating it in the first sentence.

Comment: @Ravi - not sure you got a notification on my reply.. so I am adding this comment.

Comment: You can have count like this: `count = collection.count()`

Comment: But that requires me to have 2 invocations for 'collection' one for count and another for find..

Comment: that is the only available way (that i know)...

Comment: cursor.length becaue cusor return array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, if you want to have a total count of the items and then the data you will need to have two queries, there is no other way. Why are you concerned with creating two queries?